# How to Create Json object From Selected Inputs in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to Create Json object From Selected Inputs in jquery  ?

these are my javascript codes  :

What change should I make ?

```
             let data=
                {
           "userName": $("#userName").val().trim()
           "userAddress" : $("#userAddress").val().trim()
           "userEmail" : $("#userEmail").val().trim()
           "userLname" : $("#userLname").val().trim()
            "userBio" : $("#userBio").val().trim()
            "userTeleid" : $("#userTeleId").val().trim()
            "userInsta" : "$("#userInstaId").val().trim()"
          "userCity" : $("#userCity").val().trim()
          "userWeb" : $("#userWeb").val().trim()
                };
```

Comment: Key-value pairs should be separated by commas

Comment: This is an `object` not an array

Comment: Please provide your `Selected Inputs`

Answer (score 1):

Here data is an object.
If you want to convert object to JSON, you can use JSON.stringify()

```
let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data)
```